# Unclear passages in Bishop's machine learning book for Probabilistic Generative Models

Tags: probability, machine-learning

I am trying to prove the relationship (4.65) expressed in Bishop's book ([Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](https://moodle2.units.it/pluginfile.php/99586/mod_resource/content/1/Bishop_2009_Pattern_recognition_and_machine_learning.pdf)) in chapter (4.2.1) Continuous inputs:

[image]

I found the following passages but there is one passage that I cannot understand the author's motivation:

[image]

I report the unclear passage:

$\frac{1}{2} \left [ \left ( \vec{x} - \vec{\mu_{1}} \right )^{T} \left ( \Sigma^{-1} \vec{x} - \Sigma^{-1} \vec{\mu_{1}}   \right ) \right ]$

for me:

$
\frac{1}{2} \left [\vec{x}^{T}\Sigma^{-1} \vec{x} - \vec{x}^{T}\Sigma^{-1} \vec{\mu_{1}} - \vec{\mu_{1}}^{T}\Sigma^{-1} \vec{x}  + \vec{\mu_{1}}^{T}\Sigma^{-1} \vec{\mu_{1}}\right ]$

but the author considers the following two terms to be equal:

$- \vec{x}^{T}\Sigma^{-1} \vec{\mu_{1}}$ and  $-\vec{\mu_{1}}^{T}\Sigma^{-1} \vec{x} $

Comment: They really are equal, try to think about why.

Comment: I honestly don't understand the hint

Comment: $a\in \mathbb R$ means $a^T = a$

Comment: Okay but aren't $x$ and $\mu$ vectors? and how to prove that $x^{T} = x = \mu =\mu^{T}$?

Comment: $x^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu$ is a real number

Comment: Also, note $$(x-\mu)^T(\Sigma^{-1}x-\Sigma^{-1}\mu) = (x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)$$ i.e. $\Sigma^{-1}x-\Sigma^{-1}\mu = \Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)$

Comment: thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u,v$ are $n\times 1$ matrices and $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, then as stated in the comments, $$(u^TAv)^T=u^TAv.$$ On the other hand, by properties of the transpose, $$(u^TAv)^T=v^TA^Tu.$$   If $A=A^T$, then $$u^TAv=(u^TAv)^T=v^TA^Tu=v^TAu.$$